# What is the meaning of ‘ accommodate ‘ in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The concept of indoor farming is not new, since hothouse production of tomatoes and other produce has been in vogue for some time. What is new is the urgent need to scale up this technology to **accommodate** another three billion people.

From [Solution for: Crop-growing skyscrapers](http://mini-ielts.com/386/view-solution/reading/crop-growing-skyscrapers)

Comment: Please cite the source and include the link IN the actual question and not in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good example of the kind of question that dictionaries were made to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The sense  is to “*be of help to*” another three billion people:

[To accommodate:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/accommodate)

> To take into consideration or make adjustments for; allow for:
>
> - *an economic proposal that accommodates the interests of senior citizens.*

(AHD)

Comment: Don't you think it's more like definition 3b in your linked page "_To provide for; supply with something needed_"? Agricultural production is _essential_ after all.

Comment: @BoldBen The 3b definition is for a more immediately definite provision, akin to “*gave* them stuff”. Definition 2 is more like “*allow* for expansion”, and it’s a better fit for the OP’s quote.